# Pandas/Numpy Errors in Eclipse

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working in python and eclipse for the first time and i am having troubles. This is the code I have now

```
from pandas import pandas as pd

from numpy import numpy as np

update = pd.read_csv("PPList.txt")
```

My error says that the `read_csv` is an undefined from import

My previous searches indicates that i need to change `from numpy import numpy as np` to just `import numpy *` 
When I do that, the * has an error saying that it's expecting a comma or colon.

Answer (score 0):

The imports should be

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Or

```
from pandas import *
from numpy import *
```

Comment: How do i call the read_csv then? i have update = read_csv("PPlist.txt) and i still get an error. When i change it to the first option i still get the read_csv error

Comment: @AnnaElfstrum `pd.read_csv("PPList.txt")` with the first import, `pandas.read_csv("PPList.txt")` with the second.

Comment: Unfortunately i have that and still get the error. Could i have imported something incorrectly?

Comment: @AnnaElfstrum You need `update = pd.read_csv("PPlist.txt)`, not `update = read_csv("PPlist.txt)`. You need to specify from where `read_csv` is coming from.

Comment: @AnnaElfstrum I just tried `import pandas as pd a = pd.read_csv("file path")` and it worked fine. What is the exact error? did you try full path instead of just `"PPlist.txt"`?

Comment: The exact error is undefined variable from import: read_csv. I have not tried the full path yet. where do i find that?

Comment: I think i got it figured out. I completely redid my process for the importation of pandas and the errors have gone away